How to draw the Coriolis force in 2D?
I'm studying Geophysical fluid dynamics, especially the Coriolis force.
Now, in my book, this force$^{1}$ is defined as:
$$ \vec{F_c} = -fv \hat{x} + fu \hat{y} $$
where ($u,v$) are the components of the velocity vector, $f =2\Omega\sin\phi$  with $\Omega$ is the angular speed of the frame of reference (Earth in this case), and $\phi$ is the latitude such that $f$ is positive in the northern hemisphere and negative in the southern hemisphere.
The book also says: "In practice, if a body is moving, its movement will be deflected to the right of its trajectory in the northern hemisphere and towards the left in the southern hemisphere."
What I don't understand is why when I apply $\vec{Fc}$ as a vector, I get that the Coriolis force is to the left in the northern hemisphere (for a positive f):
$$\vec{V} = (u,v)$$
$$\vec{V} + \vec{F_c} = (u,v) + (-fv,fu) $$
$$\vec{V_R} = (u-fv,v+fu) $$
In the following sketch, I draw $F_c$ to indicate the change in velocity (acceleration).

Am I doing something wrong? Or this is related to the fact that Coriolis force is a pseudovector?
1 In my book, the momentum balances are given in forces per unit mass, by which $F_c$ is considered a force.

You're making the assumption here that $\hat{x}$ stands for east and $\hat{y}$ stands for north. Are you sure that's the case? Perhaps it is stated more explicitly what they are in the book?

Yes, I'm sure that is the case. In the introduction part of the book they say that the convention will (u, v, w) as the velocity components. Edit: Well, they also say that the east-west velocity will be denoted as u, north-south as v and the vertical velocity as w.

well then the formula seems to be at odds with the one given here on Wikipedia. They have: $$ \mathbf{a}_c = f(v_n\hat{x}-v_e\hat{y}).$$ Either I'm missing something obvious, or the book is just wrong.

when you say "pseudo-vector", do you mean that it is even under parity reversal (particle physics definition) or that it depends on the definition of the origin (not particle physics definition)?

@emek I missed the edit you made to the comment. See my answer, it may clarify things anyway. But now that I see your edit too: when they write "east-west" velocity, do they mean that the west direction is positive? Same question about $v$. Sometimes "east-west" stands for "east to west"... and then that can explain the opposite sign they seem to be having.

Regarding the title: "How do I draw...", if you consider a vector potential in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi, z)$:
$$ \vec A = \Omega\rho\hat\phi $$
(which is just the velocity of a fixed coordinate point's rotation according to an inertial frame) and find it's force field by the usual means:
$$ \vec B = \vec\nabla\times\vec A = 2\vec\Omega $$
you then get the force on a test mass (a la the Lorentz formula):
$$ \vec F_C = m\vec v \times \vec B $$
which becomes the recognizable Coriolis formula:
$$ \vec F_C = -2m\vec \Omega \times \vec v $$
So the answer is: you draw it like a uniform magnetic field proportional to $2\vec\Omega$.
The other question "Am I doing something wrong?", that has two answers:
One is concrete: you appear to have a sign error in $v_{East}$
Another is more abstract: you're getting tied up in components, when the coordinate free description is a lot clear, imho.
Let's make a 3rd: why not use standard "LTP" (local tangent plane) coordinates with a heading of $0^{\circ}$ (heading north), the you can use NED$^1$ (North-East-Down) coordinates instead of $(u, v)$ or is it $(v, u)$? No need to add extra confusion.
[1] People also use ENU (East-North-Up). Since you're not worried about vertical motion, ENU is nice because it looks like standard cartesian $x-y$ plane on a map. Of course it easy to switch back and force, but the less overhead you put in you coordinates, the better things will be.

Thanks for your answer. However, I'm still lost. In Kundu's sixth edition book, for example, equations 13.5 and 13.6 define the Coriolis acceleration as $(-fv,fu,-2\Omega u \cos \eta)$ with $f = 2\Omega \sin \theta$. This is exactly how the force is defined in my professor's book. So, how can I have a wrong sign there? Edit: The whole point why am I asking this is because I'm trying to plot the Coriolis force based on real (u,v) data, but I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a wrong coordinate axis. That's the whole problem. Thanks for your help.

@emek that's what's I'm saying. $u$ and $v$ are easy to swap, so I like to put things is recognizable coordinates that match my "mental picture", which for me, is a sheet of graph paper aligned $x=$ East, $y=$North as if were on my school desk in front of me, or if I'm in my office with my globe, I'll draw $xy$ on paper  and hold it there at some north latitude. Then I use $v_x$, $v_y$...though I used to make maps for NASA (SRTM & NASADEM), so I'll think in East, North, Up just as well. Trivial mental swaps like y-> $\pm$j -> $\mp$u with $P_{error}=0.01$ per swap add up (or multiply).

It seems like the book is wrong, or some other misunderstanding has occurred somewhere.
Either way, we can calculate the direction of the Coriolis force for the case of a counterclockwise rotating system, which the northern hemisphere is (as seen from above the north pole).
We take $\boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}} = \omega \boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$, where $\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$ points towards the north pole. By the right hand rule then, with $\omega>0$, this represents a counterclockwise rotation. As per your book's notation, we put $\boldsymbol{\vec{V}} = u\boldsymbol{\hat{x}}+v\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}$, and apply the standard Coriolis force formula:
$$ \boldsymbol{\vec{F}_{\text{coriolis}}} = -2m\ \boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}}\times\boldsymbol{\vec{V}} = -2m\begin{vmatrix} \boldsymbol{\hat{x}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{y}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{z}}  \\ 0 & 0 & \omega \\ u & v & 0 \end{vmatrix} = 2m\omega\left(v\boldsymbol{\hat{x}}-u\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}\right) $$
This not only demonstrates that objects in such a system travelling towards the north should be deflected eastwards, but also that objects travelling to the east are deflected southwards, which indicates a clockwise pattern of deflection. This indeed is the well known deflection pattern that's due to the Coriolis effect in the northern hemisphere, as seen for example in the following schematic representation:


Kes47, CC BY-SA 3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0, via Wikimedia Commons

Thanks for clarifying. I have a wrong coordinate axis.
